# Prolog constraint logic programming - How to set a domain on a List of Domain Variables given a List of Integers?

Tags: prolog, clpfd

Basically what I want to achieve is :

Given a list of domain Variables set these Variables with a domain relative to a List of Numbers. Example:

......

```
List=[A1,A2,A3],
domain(List,1,5],
setDomain(List,[1,2]),
labeling([],List).
```

Result:

```
A1=1, A2=1, A3=1 or
A1=1, A2=1, A3=2 or
A1=1, A2=2, A3=1
```

and so on...

What I have tried:

```
setDomain(List,ListIntegers):-
  element(X, List, Element),
  member(Element,ListIntegers),

main(List):-
  List=[A1,A2,A3],
  domain(List,1,5],
  setDomain(List,[1,2]),
  labeling([],List).
```

but not success...

Can anyone help understand how can I accomplish this?

Comment: edit: remove that line with domain(List,1,5)...

Comment: Why don't you just edit and correct your question? You don't need to leave editorial notes in the comments. And can you be specific when you say, *but not success*?

Comment: So basically you have a list of variables and you want to set the domain of each variable using a predicate which has as input the domain to set, right?

Comment: Do you want a list of 3 elements where each element is in the domain [1,2]? That would simply be, `length(List, 3), List ins 1..2, label(List).` You don't need the more verbose `labeling([], List)`. Or do you mean an arbitary list of integers as a domain? Your example doesn't make that clear...

Comment: @damianodamiano yes, thats it!

Comment: @lurker what I meant was precisely that arbitrary list of integers as a domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution, you're using `labeling/2` but haven't defined its arguments using CLP(FD), so it doesn't do anything for you. It's not very clear from your question or simple example, but it sounds like you want a list of a given length whose elements are each taken from a domain consisting of an arbitrary list of elements?

You could do so with something like this:

```
member_(List, Element) :- member(Element, List).

domain_list(Length, Domain, List) :-
    length(List, Length),
    maplist(member_(Domain), List).
```

This would give:

```
6 ?- domain_list(3, [1,3], L).
L = [1, 1, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 3] ;
L = [1, 3, 1] ;
L = [1, 3, 3] ;
L = [3, 1, 1] ;
L = [3, 1, 3] ;
L = [3, 3, 1] ;
L = [3, 3, 3].

7 ?-
```

This also works for any kind of elements:

```
7 ?- domain_list(3, [tom, a(b)], L).
L = [tom, tom, tom] ;
L = [tom, tom, a(b)] ;
L = [tom, a(b), tom] ;
L = [tom, a(b), a(b)] ;
L = [a(b), tom, tom] ;
L = [a(b), tom, a(b)] ;
L = [a(b), a(b), tom] ;
L = [a(b), a(b), a(b)].

8 ?-
```

If you wanted to use CLP(FD), you'd need to keep a couple of things in mind. CLP(FD) is for integer domains, and CLP(FD) has its own way of specifying domains, which is not in list form.

For instance, if you wanted a list of length `N` whose elements were in the domain described by `[1,2,3,5,6,8]`, you would write it as:

```
length(List, N),
List ins 1..3 \/ 5..6 \/ 8,
label(List).
```

Which would result in, for example:

```
2 ?- length(List, 3), List ins 1..3 \/ 5..6 \/ 8, label(List).
List = [1, 1, 1] ;
List = [1, 1, 2] ;
List = [1, 1, 3] ;
List = [1, 1, 5] ;
List = [1, 1, 6] ;
List = [1, 1, 8] ;
List = [1, 2, 1] ;
List = [1, 2, 2]
...
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! But now what I really need is that case where I simply don't know what are the numbers of that list of integers. So, I just can't do like  List ins 1..3 \/ 5..6 \/ 8 because I Don't know what are the values of that list, am I being clear ? So that would be something like length(List, 3,ListOfIngers) and the ListOfIntegers could be something like [9,8,11,20,...].

Comment: @mljistcart can't you just use the first solution I provided then? CLP(FD) in SWI Prolog doesn't have a mechanism for defining a domain based upon an arbitrary list of integers. But then you don't need CLP(FD) for your solution it seems. In your own solution attempt, the only CLP(FD) call you made is `labeling/2` which served no CLP(FD) purpose on its own.

Comment: of course! Your first solution gives me precisely what I need ... Thanks again. However, it seems to give me (sometimes) repeated solutions. It is normal to happen?

Comment: @mljistcart can you give me an example of a repeated solution? If list position matters, then the solutions should be unique I think. Also, if you find my answer acceptable, perhaps you could click the accept check mark.

Answer (score 1):

Using ECLiPSe Prolog you can write:

```
:-lib(fd).

applyDomain([],_).
applyDomain([H|T],D):-
    var_fd(H,D),
    applyDomain(T,D).

domainList(ListDomain,LengthList,ListOutput):-
    length(ListOutput,LengthList),
    list_to_dom(ListDomain,Domain),
    applyDomain(ListOutput,Domain).
```

Query:

```
?- domainList([2,3,5,7,8],5,L).
L = [_530{[2, 3, 5, 7, 8]}, _547{[2, 3, 5, 7, 8]}, _564{[2, 3, 5, 7, 8]}, _581{[2, 3, 5, 7, 8]}, _598{[2, 3, 5, 7, 8]}]
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

The output means that each variable (in this case `_530`, `_547` and so on) in the list `L` has the specified domain `{[2, 3, 5, 7, 8]}`. If you want to label the list you can simply add

```
labeling(ListOutput).
```

as last line of `domainList/3` and you get:

```
?- domainList([2, 3, 5, 7, 8], 5, L).
L = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more)
L = [2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 2, maybe more)
L = [2, 2, 2, 2, 5]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 3, maybe more)
```

and so on... If you want that all the list will be different, just add

```
alldifferent(ListOutput),
```

before `labeling/1`, and you'll get

```
?- domainList([2, 3, 5, 7, 8], 5, L).
L = [2, 3, 5, 7, 8]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more)
L = [2, 3, 5, 8, 7]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 2, maybe more)
L = [2, 3, 7, 5, 8]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 3, maybe more)
```

I usually don't use SWI prolog for `clpfd` problems, so i don't know if there is a similar solution in SWI...

Comment: thanks for your answer! I am current using SICstus, and here I don't have that predicate called  var_fd. Do you know an equivalent one?

Comment: the same for list_to_dom . I think that one could be replaced as list_to_fdset